# Fundraising event - can I sell tickets AND collect donations?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, contributions, contribution-page, price-sets

My organization is hosting a fundraising event at which the tickets are not expensive and participants can contribute an additional amount as well. How would you set this up? Currently I have a price list for the tickets, but I'm unsure how to do the write-in additional contribution. Linking to the donate page could be done, but isn't ideal. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

one way you could do this is to create one field in your priceset for the ticket (probably making it required to ensure that they actually purchase tickets), and then another field (not required) that's a text field with a value set to 1 (which will multiply by the amount they enter), e.g., https://www.screencast.com/t/Db1nHAWfA (You can also set the financial type to something besides Event Fee for the additional contribution, if desired.)

Lesley

Comment: Exactly - that's how - the Financial Typing is going to be important if you're going to be issuing Charitable Donation Tax Receipts.